# Mysterious ~1min delay in HTTP POST between browser and Nginx

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, nginx, xmlhttprequest, tastypie

We've lately been experiencing a very strange but very consistent delay when POSTing from client-side javascript to our server.

**Here's our technology stack, from front to back:**

1. Custom javascript client code
2. Backbone.js
3. [Custom Backbone.sync() implementation](https://gist.github.com/3789008)
4. jQuery.ajax() (1.7.2)
5. XmlHttpRequest
6. Browser (verified on both Firefox and Chrome)
7. Internet
8. Nginx front-end
9. Intranet (via Nginx `http://` upstream)
10. Nginx back-end
11. Gunicorn (via Nginx `unix://` upstream socket)
12. Django 1.4
13. django-tastypie

(Side note: do you ever just step back in awe at how *complicated* web development is?)

**Here's a timeline of events:**

1. Client code calls `.save()` on a newly created Backbone [`APIModel`](https://gist.github.com/3789008#L358).
2. Our custom [`.sync()`](https://gist.github.com/3789008#L245) winds its way to [`client.send()`](https://gist.github.com/3789008#L180) which dispatches the newly created object to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
3. The resulting XmlHttpRequest POSTs. The request appears in the browser dev tool's Network pane, marked as *pending*.
4. The HTTP request reaches Nginx, which routes it to the django-tastypie backend.
5. Tastypie handles the request promptly and flawlessly, creating the resource, and returning a 201 CREATED response, with a `Location` header pointing to the new resource.
6. Nginx logs the request and (ostensibly) sends the response.
7. **1.1 minutes elapse,** during which the request is still marked as *pending* in the Network pane.
8. The request is marked as complete in the browser's Network pane.
9. The jQuery `xhr` fires success handlers
10. Our custom API client's [success handler](https://gist.github.com/3789008#L223) detects the 201 response code and fires off a subsequent GET request to the Location.
11. The usual stuff happens, the GET responds promptly, and the outermost `$.Deferred()` object resolves, firing any associated client code success handlers.

**Other details to consider:**

1. GET requests and PUT requests in the same stack resolve promptly.
2. When interacting directly with the outermost Nginx via a dedicated HTTP client, POST requests identical to the request in question resolve promptly.
3. Removing the special-case 201 handler and subsequent GET has no effect on the bug.
4. The delay is *always* 1.1 minutes. I've used `console.time()` to determine that the delay varies within the 65,000ms range.
5. The delay only appears in this configuration. It does not occur in our development setups, which are slightly simpler.

**Unverified assumptions I'm making:**

1. Once Nginx logs a request, the response has been tied up with a bow and sent to the client with a handwritten thank-you note.
2. This is not a bug in the browsers or in jQuery.

Forgive the painstaking detail, but I've done my best to eliminate variables, and at present, I feel safe in saying that the problem is one of the following:

1. a flaw in the physical structure of the universe
2. a flaw in the perceptual models of our minds
3. something else we haven't considered yet

I'm hoping for #3. Any ideas?

Comment: _When interacting directly with the server via a dedicated HTTP client, POST requests identical to the request in question resolve promptly._ -> Which Server exactly ?

Comment: Good question. The outermost Nginx. Updated the Other Details to reflect this.

Comment: Sounds like there's some sort of timeout watchdog firing, as if the HTTP response isn't being properly closed.

Comment: @Pointy Interesting. I'm working under the assumption that once Nginx has logged a request, the response has been tied up with a little bow and sent on its way. I don't know if this is a correct assumption.

Comment: I think it's probably logging the beginning of the response, not necessarily the end.  Remember that a response may contain a *lot* of data.  The server behind nginx has to finish the response; in some environments that's done with something like closing a file descriptor - I don't know how Python stacks work.

Comment: Maybe you could create a dummy URL backed by some very simple code so that you can do a test POST with code involved that's more under your control.

Comment: @Pointy Nginx logs the size of the response in bytes, which is why I've made this assumption. Nginx is communicating with the upstream via a `unix:` file socket.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17199/discussion-between-david-eyk-and-pointy)

Comment: I would recommend you to compare `Content-Length` of the response (if any) with actual response body size as returned by your backend code. As nginx normally uses non-persistent connections to upstream servers it wouldn't notice if `Content-Length` is incorrect, but if it is your browser may wait for more data till some timeout. As a quick test you may try adding `keepalive_timeout 0;` to frontend nginx config.

Comment: @MaximDounin Since the body is empty, there is no Content-Length header. That was a good idea, though.

Comment: @MaximDounin It *was* the missing Content-Length header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery solved! It was the `Content-Length` header, or rather, the lack of one. @MaxDounin had the right idea, I just didn't follow it far enough.

Enabling Django's `django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware` did the trick. (This middleware sets the `Content-Length` header.)

Comment: Missing Content-Length header isn't a reason for a delay unless there is a bug somewhere. While it may be enough to set Content-Length to resolve the issue, it is still unknown what the issue is.

Comment: We're running a fairly ancient Nginx: 0.7.65-1ubuntu2 (Ubuntu Lucid). Perhaps I should have made note of that?