# MVC GET Action takes 0.1 second, the same POST Action takes 30 seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-get

Given the two Actions in an ASP.NET MVC controller which return the same thing, but one handles GET requests and one handles POST requests. The GET Action always returns in 0.1 second and the POST Action always returns in 30 seconds. The action itself completes very quickly but for some reason, the browser (IE and Chrome) shows as waiting for 30 secs in the Network Profiler - what could be causing the delay? Is there any way I can debug this?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View("MyView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(object obj)
    {
        return View("MyView");
    }
```

Network profile for each:

http://MyDevServer.com:8080/MyController/MyAction
Method: GET
Status: 200 OK
Time: 0.194 seconds

http://MyDevServer.com:8080/MyController/MyAction
Method: POST
Status: 200 OK
Time: 30.39 seconds

Comment: Is this hosted in IIS?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the POST-version of you action method, does the request take a while to reach the action method, or does it get there quick but takes a while returning to the client?

Comment: You shuould look for problem in your code (show us your real code in ActionResult) on in db.connection.

Comment: Agreed. There should be no difference between these two actions, so there must be something in your real code that's causing the problem.

Comment: 1. on my Dev server, 2. It reaches, and steps over, the return method really quickly, and then takes ages to return to the client. 3. This is the real code - just variable names changed, I agree there should be no difference - it's a site with Razor and ASP view engines, the framework I am trying to add is DevExpress and these actions are for one of the controls. How can I profile what is going on between the Action returning and the Browser receiving? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look into:

1. Do you have a piece of code that is hooking into the stack and delaying execution, a view engine, a filter or provider? You will be able to find this out by using a profiler like [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.telerik.com/analytics/eqatec-profiler) (damn it's been taken over by Telerik, but it's still free until the end of the year).

   1a. Are you letting MVC find your views in the standard way? Are you adding to the ViewLocations in any way?
2. What is happening on your server? Are you seeing any performance spikes as the POST moves through to indicate something untoward occurring?
3. What happens when you remove the object argument? Any change?
4. You say that this *is* the code. Are you using Entity Framework in this project? [This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/02/20/disabling-change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx) can increase performance significantly on occasion depending upon setup.
5. Describe your Application Pool in IIS. Mode? Other settings?

Comment: I have deployed in IIS and there is no issue, so the problem is only in my dev server. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606898/mysterious-1min-delay-in-http-post-between-browser-and-nginx which suggested the Content-Length but I've checked and this is being sent correctly